# Is it possible to generate a hiberfil.sys (generate a full image of memory) without shutting down a computer?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, system, file-permissions

I had an idea for a potential lifesaving program for people who work with important data and don't save frequently enough.By taking advantage of the Hibernate functionality on Windows, would it be possible to generate a hiberfil.sys without shutting down the machine afterwards to get a full image of memory at regular intervals?

i have this code:

```
// Hibernate
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Hibernate, true, true);
```

but don't have a possibility to generate an image of memory without putting system to hibernate.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do this without a noticeable performance hit. One option would be to suspend all CPU cores, disable interrupts, save all paged in RAM, and compress the file. I'm not sure off the top of my head what the format of hiberfile.sys is, you would need it to match if you want it to work the same. I don't see this as a good idea anyway, you'll be saving a huge amount of memory that doesn't matter (i.e anything other than work being manually done such as code or documents.)

Comment: I should probably clarify since your example code is user mode, there is absolutely no way to do what you want from that privilege level. The process you are executing from can only access its own memory or memory it's explicitly given access to. The RAM of the currently running process by itself isn't enough to simply reload it after a system restart, expected fields in the PEB / TEB will be invalid for example.